# Are certificates generated from Jrockit JDK1.6 keytool forward compatible with JDK 1.8

Tags: java, ssl

I am doing feasibility analysis of upgrading my application, which is till now running on Weblogic 10.3.6, to run on Weblogic 12.1.3.
The previously existing application used Jrockit 1.6 JVM.
Linux is the environment.
We used to generate certificates by using the keytool provided with Jrockit 1.6.

Now, as part of the upgrade we going to using Jdk 1.8 with weblogic 12.1.3.

AS, we run into issues, I wanted to know if the certificates, which were created using the Jrockit JDK 1.6 keytool, will work with JDK 1.8.
Or, do we need to generate them afresh with the JDK 1.8 keytool?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Certificate formats are defined by ITU X.509 and Internet RFCs, not by Java.

I have been submitting the same CSR to my CA for several years, certainly dating back to Java 1.6 if not 1.5. I'll keep doing that until I need to re-key or something else breaks.